# SparseMatrix and Vector addition broadcasting in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I want to add a dense `VectorXf` to a `SparseMatrix`, and I know that I could do matrix + vector easily for dense matrix, [like this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html)

```
  Eigen::MatrixXf mat(2,4);
  Eigen::VectorXf v(2);

  mat << 1, 2, 6, 9,
         3, 1, 7, 2;

  v << 0,
       1;

  //add v to each column of m
  mat.colwise() += v;
```

but how to do this for sparse matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to iterate over all columns and add a sparse vector to your sparse matrix. And you should keep in mind, that if you need colwise operation, your matrix should be stored as Column-Major.

```
// allocate dense object
Eigen::MatrixXd M(2,4);
Eigen::VectorXd v(2);
// allocate sparse vector
Eigen::SparseVector<double> spV(2);
// allocate Column-major sparse matrix
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor> spM(2, 4);
// initialize dense objects values
M << 1, 0, 0, 2,
     4, 5, 0, 0;
v << 1,
     3;
// convert dense objects to sparse representation
spM = M2.sparseView();
spV = v2.sparseView();
// iterate over sparse Matrix columns
for(int i = 0; i< spM.cols(); ++i) {
  spM.col(i) += spV;
}
```

It can't be done in such way for dense vector and one of the reason is that this operation does not make any sense, since the resulting matrix will be dense. In this case you will need to create some dense matrix and perform colwise operation with your dense vector like this:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd(spM).colwise() + v
```

Comment: thanks and pretty clear, actually what I'm doing right now is the same as you said, i.e. iterate all the columns and do `spM.col(i) += spV`, and since dense matrix has such a convenient method `.colwise()` without iterating the columns, so I just posted this question to confirm if we could do this `.colwise` thing for sparse matrix :-)

Comment: @avocado As isakoff already stated, the result is dense anyways, so you should probably just convert the sparse matrix to a dense one and continue on from there. `Eigen::MatrixXd(spM).colwise() + v` does not give you a sparse matrix, it gives you a dense temporary matrix (at least, it does once evaluated).

Comment: @AviGinsburg, so `Eigen::MatrixXd(spM).colwise() + v` will create a dense matrix anyway, right? If yes, then I might not take this route, since the sparse matrix I'm dealing with is quite huge.

Comment: @avocado It's not the way you write it that makes it dense, it's the operation itself. 'v' is dense (at least you specifically stated that you "want to add a dense 'VectorXf' to a 'SparseMatrix'") making the result dense.

Comment: @AviGinsburg, oh I see, so since the result is dense anyway, that means I would run into memory issues if the sparse matrix is huge, right?

Comment: Memory issues will be similar whether dense or sparse. But because your "sparse" matrix is dense, all the memory accesses later will cost a lot more than the comparable dense matrix.